# Extract row from dataframe and output as a single line in R

Tags: r, subset

If you are curious this is a bit of **background** for my question (it is probably not necessary so you could skip the first bit here):

I am currently writing a script (`multi_gene`) in which it reads in another R script (`sngle_gene`) and runs that. It is supposed to perform a loop so that it will run multiple iterations of `sngle_gene`. The `sngle_gene` script also works by calling arguments from the command line, so I have been trying to figure out a way to have the `multi_gene` script input these arguments (so that I don't have to edit the `sngle_gene` script, so that it can still take arguments from the command line).

My solution has been to get `multi_gene` to add all the command line arguments at the end of a source command:

```
source(paste(paste(directory, "sngle_gene.R", sep = ""), arguments, sep = " "))
```

**Background over**, here is my question:

I want to read in a dataframe of arguments for inputting so that the loop I am creating will go through each row in the table and use each row as the list of arguments (which are strings and numbers) for `arguments`. In my head then it will output as something line:

```
/directory/sngle_gene.R argument1 argument2 argument3 etc
```

I tried extracting single lines from my table with:

```
arguments = unlist(test_df[1, ], use.names = F)
```

Which seemed to provide a list of my arguments, except then it printed like this:

```
/directory/sngle_gene.R argument1
/directory/sngle_gene.R argument2
```

And I'm not really sure how to go about fixing that so that it will all come out on one line. Any help appreciated.

**Edit for clarification:** Also, I am aware that using `test_df[1,]` will just read the first row. In the loop I use a variable instead of a number.

Comment: `paste("/directory/sngle_gene.R", paste(arguments, collapse = " "))`?

Comment: Please add an example `data.frame` to your question to show us the input

Comment: @RuiBarradas that's perfect! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @RYoda, to be honest for the purposes of this question the contents of the DF don't seem that important. It's a table of 7 rows including numbers and strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an implicit loop over the rows use `apply` with the argument `MARGIN` set to `1`:

```
test_df <- data.frame(arg1 = c("arg1.1", "arg1.2", "arg1.3"),
                      arg2 = c("arg2.1", "arg2.2", "arg2.3"))
test_df

#   arg1   arg2
# 1 arg1.1 arg2.1
# 2 arg1.2 arg2.2
# 3 arg1.3 arg2.3

script.name <- "/directory/sngle_gene.R"

res <- data.frame(cmdline = paste(script.name, apply(test_df, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "))))
res

#   cmdline
# 1 /directory/sngle_gene.R arg1.1 arg2.1
# 2 /directory/sngle_gene.R arg1.2 arg2.2
# 3 /directory/sngle_gene.R arg1.3 arg2.3
```

Comment: While it looks like this will do exactly what I want, I think that the solution in the comments under my initial post actually solves my problem a little more neatly. Although I assume using ```apply``` might be more robust, it just doesn't seem necessary. Thanks very much!